# delimiter with utf-16 encoding

Tags: csv, python-3.4

I need to write some data into a csv file. The data includes characters from Chinese and English so I need to use utf-16 encoding. The problem is that if I use utf-16 encoding then ',' is not used as the delimiter in the csv. The code below shows what I mean.

```
# with no encoding
import csv

headers = ['Name', 'Date', 'Blahblah']
with open('out.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel', delimiter=',')
    csvwriter.writerow(headers)
```

OUTPUT
|Name|Date|Blahblah| (the | indicates a cell, each entry in its own cell)

```
# using utf-16 encoding
import csv

headers = ['Name', 'Date', 'Blahblah']
with open('out.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-16', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel', delimiter=',')
    csvwriter.writerow(headers)
```

OUTPUT:
|Name,Date,Blahblah| # all entries in a single cell

How do I make the comma delimiter work with utf-16 encoding? I'm guessing I need to specify some sort of escape sequence in 'encoding=...', but I'm not sure what.

I'm using Python 3.4.5 because I need several other modules that only work with this version.

Comment: "The data includes characters from Chinese and English so I need to use utf-16 encoding." That is not how encoding works. As for your attempts to "force" UTF-16: you cannot "tell" a file to use a certain encoding *if it is not encoded as such*. Either the file *is* UTF-16 or it is not – you cannot *decide* to read it as such. So determine what it is and adjust your code for that. Add a link to a small test file and we can take a look.

Comment: I'm trying to write data into a csv file. If I don't specify an encoding then I get this error when trying to write Chinese chars:
UnicodeEncodeError - 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position xy: character maps to 'undefined'

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use the comma separator because it's not supported by 'UTF-16' encoding. Try using the tab delimiter with code `delimiter='\t'`. It solved my problem